# precompiled static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

I want to add a pre-compiled static C library (it was not compiled by the Android toolchain) to my Android project and give the library file rwx permissions. can this be done without root access?

Comment: "it was not compiled by the Android toolchain" then it's probably not going to work on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to change file permissions for a static library. This file only exists on your build machine. You must build a shared library (file with **.so** extension) and make sure it is packed into your APK. You don't need to worry about file permissions for the shared library: the system installer will unpack this file into the expected location on the device, and apply appropriate permissions there. This file will be globally readable, but neither the file nor its directory will be writeable, even from your app.